# Is there an API for item creation?

Tags: best-practices, sitecore-services-client

We're in the process of integrating with a product management tool to automate the process of item/product creation within our system.  I know that Sitecore has the ability to pass back the objects directly through URL reference, but is there a way to pass a JSON object, or something like that, which would be able to include a reference to a template maybe, and a location/parent node to save it to, and create a new instance of the item, and save it appropriately?

We do something like that now in our manual process, which can create an item based on an excel spreadsheet, but that was entirely home-grown, and programmatically creates the item (or version if it's already there) and that get's saved back where it belongs.

*Is there anything out of the box that sitecore provides that would perform that object creation?*

Comment: Hey Jon, have you heard of Sitecore PowerShell Extensions? It's not an out of the box solution but does offer the ability to build your own API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Item Web API

For Sitecore versions from 6+ till 8 you should use the **Sitecore Item Web API**.

Documentation is available here: [link](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc65-66-usletter.pdf)

> **Creating an Item from a Template**
>
> To create an item called **MyItem** that is based on the **Sample Item** template in the **master** database, use
>   a URL in the following format:
>
> **http:///-
>   /item/v1/sitecore/Content/Home?name=MyItem&template=Sample/Sample
>   Item&sc_database=master**

### Sitecore Services Client

For newer Sitecore versions (8+) the **Sitecore.Services.Client** must be used:

Please, check this document by Sitecore (*p.3.4.5 Create an Item*):
[link](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/75/developer's_guide_to_sitecore.services.client_sc75-a4.pdf)

> You use this method to create a new Sitecore item.
>
> Verb: **POST**
>
> URL:  **/item/{path}?database&language**

Comment: A couple of comments... I tried this first piece (same as below... if I had more points for the board, I'd upvote both) but all I was able to do with the suggested urls (with querystring parameters) was get a returned piece of json, which seemed to be the home node.  So it seemed like I was getting the correct location and format, but seemed like I was hitting a get() and not an insert... that all being said, we're using 7.2 now, but redoing the site in 8.2 later in the year... looks like a different implementation would be needed anyway... is there any way to use the newer way on 7.2

Comment: @Jon the new method is available from 7.5 onwards

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the Sitecore ItemService API to do this like so:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://<your server>/sitecore/api/ssc/item/sitecore%2Fcontent%2Fhome ");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
    alert('Status: '+this.status+'\nHeaders: '+JSON.stringify(this.getAllResponseHeaders())+'\nBody: '+this.responseText);
  }
};
xhr.send("{ \n    \"ItemName\": \"Home\", \n    \"TemplateID\": \"76036f5e-cbce-46d1-af0a-4143f9b557aa\", \n    \"Title\": \"Sitecore\", \n    \"Text\": \"\\r\\n\\t\\t\u003Cp\u003EWelcome to Sitecore\u003C/p\u003E\\r\\n\" \n}");
```

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/the_restful_api_for_the_itemservice

Answer (score 2):

You can use sitecore Sitecore Item Web API to create an item.

```
http://[host_name]/-/item/v1/sitecore/Content/Home?name=MyItem&template=Sample/Sample Item&sc_database=master
```

Also make sure you have these settings in your **Sitecore.ItemWebApi.config**

```
itemwebapi.mode="StandardSecurity"
itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false"/>
```

For more info https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc65-66-usletter.pdf